# DateTime parsing to unintended value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

`Error: Input string was in incorrect format` when executing `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedOn)`

This parse code `DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01")` parses to the format `'02-Jan-2016 10:00:01 AM'`, what am I missing?

Even `DateTime.ParseExact("02/01/2016 10:00:01", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` parses to the same.

C# DateTime library, running in ASP.NET MVC.

This is the code:

```
protected override void Seed(PrimaryContext context)
        {
            var stories = new List<Story>();
            var loremIpsum = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum felis in nibh lobortis bibendum et ut lorem. 
                Donec viverra nisi eget erat molestie, a molestie mauris dictum. Cras vel dui et nulla condimentum lobortis vel et nisi. 
                Sed hendrerit turpis feugiat justo malesuada elementum. Sed elementum tortor eu nunc consequat, at sollicitudin quam laoreet. 
                Nunc mattis, sem sit amet efficitur sodales, quam nunc interdum justo, et hendrerit ex massa at purus. Quisque interdum nisi dolor, eu congue nunc consequat at. 
                Vestibulum porta tempor urna, in pellentesque nunc varius molestie. 
                Sed lacus neque, faucibus vitae est eu, convallis bibendum quam. Nullam ut bibendum odio. Fusce tristique sed tellus ac volutpat. 
                Sed ut quam erat. Proin in diam ut velit tincidunt finibus. Morbi porta et quam non faucibus. Sed viverra varius tristique.
                Phasellus sollicitudin enim sit amet urna interdum bibendum.";
            stories.Add(new Story() { Title = "Story " + 0, Body = loremIpsum, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01") });
            stories.Add(new Story() { Title = "Story " + 1, Body = loremIpsum, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01") });
            stories.Add(new Story() { Title = "Story " + 2, Body = loremIpsum, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01") });
            stories.Add(new Story() { Title = "Story " + 3, Body = loremIpsum, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01") });
            stories.Add(new Story() { Title = "Story " + 4, Body = loremIpsum, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01") });
            stories.Add(new Story() { Title = "Story " + 5, Body = loremIpsum, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01") });
            stories.Add(new Story() { Title = "Story " + 6, Body = loremIpsum, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01") });
            stories.Add(new Story() { Title = "Story " + 7, Body = loremIpsum, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01") });
            stories.Add(new Story() { Title = "Story " + 8, Body = loremIpsum, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01") });
            stories.Add(new Story() { Title = "Story " + 9, Body = loremIpsum, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01") });
            stories.Add(new Story() { Title = "Story " + 10, Body = loremIpsum, CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2016 10:00:01") });
            stories.ForEach(s => context.Stories.Add(s));
            base.Seed(context);
        }
```

It fails when attempting to display the DateTime with `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedOn)`

Stack trace

"   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)\r\n   at 
System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)\r\n   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor[TContainer,TValue](HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor[TContainer,TValue](HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor[TModel,TValue](HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression)\r\n   at ASP._Page_Views_stories_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\users\g\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\fcon\fcon\Views\stories\Index.cshtml:line 41\r\n   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()\r\n   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()\r\n   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()\r\n   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)"

Comment: please show the stack for the first exception.

Comment: Apologies for it not being in code format, it would have been only one line that way.

Comment: sounds like a bug in asp.net mvc.

Comment: is `item.CreatedOn` is a `DateTime` type variable?

Comment: Bah humbug. Thanks for looking into it, I'll just use the default DateTime format then.

Comment: @gypsyCoder yes I declare it as [DataType(DataType.DateTime)] with DataFormatString "{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}"

Comment: can you please try it as following `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedOn.ToString())` @Johnath

Comment: Thank you sir! Silly of me, of course it just displays the DateTime object. doh!